# ParserError message when compiling solidity code

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I'm following a blockchain and smart contract course, and the code I'm trying to run doesn't seem to compile, even though it's the exact same one from the course. I can't say much more about the program since I'm a newbie and I'm just trying to follow along, and I can't find out if there's a syntax error or if it's something else. All I can say, is that I'm using an imported smart contract that I coded in the past lesson and it works perfectly fine.

**Specific error:** *contracts/StorageFactory.sol:20:5: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum definition.
function sfGet(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex) public view returns (uint256) {
^------^*

**code 1:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity  ^0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {

//this will get initialized to 0!
uint256 favoriteNumber;
bool favoriteBool;

struct People {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;
    string name;
}

People[] public people;
mapping(string => uint256) public nametoFavoriteNumber;

function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
    favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
}
function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
    return favoriteNumber;
}

function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
    people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
    nametoFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
}
}
```

**code 2:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity  ^0.6.0;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

contract StorageFactory {
SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;
function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
    SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
    simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
}
function sfStore(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex, uint256 _simpleStorageNumber) public {
    // Address
    // ABI
    SimpleStorage simpleStorage = SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex]));
    simpleStorage.store(_simpleStorageNumber);
}
}
function sfGet(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex) public view returns (uint256) {
    SimpleStorage simpleStorage = SimpleStorage(address(SimpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex]));
    return simpleStorage.retrieve();
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using remix to compile the code?

Comment: yes, I'm using remix, just like in the course

Comment: What compiler version are you using?

Comment: 0.6.12+commit.27d51765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sfStore()` function you have put two curly brackets at the end. This is your code:

```
function sfStore(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex, uint256 _simpleStorageNumber) public {
    // Address
    // ABI
    SimpleStorage simpleStorage = SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex]));
    simpleStorage.store(_simpleStorageNumber);
} 
} // <- THE ERROR IS HERE
```

You delete one curly bracket and you'll resolve this problem.
The new `sfStore` function code must be similar this:

```
function sfStore(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex, uint256 _simpleStorageNumber) public {
  // Address
  // ABI
  SimpleStorage simpleStorage = 
  SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex]));
  simpleStorage.store(_simpleStorageNumber);
}
```